# Why setdaemon property is not ending the child thread when main thread has ended?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I am running following peice of code to understand daemon threads concept and thread termination. the program keeps printing even after main method is done. Am I missing something here?

```
package threading;

public class ThreadInterruption {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new RanThread());
        t.start();
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.interrupt();
    }

}

class RanThread implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count=0;
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Ha Ha Ha "+ count);
            count=count+1;

        }

    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the thread as a daemon before you start it.

If you read the API docs it states "This method must be invoked before the thread is started."

So swap the start and setDaemon lines and you should be good.